# Google Cloud ML Engine: Using Tensorflow 1.10?

Tags: tensorflow

I've trained a Keras model using Tensorflow 1.10.  However, I only see up to Tensorflow 1.9 on ML Engine when I create a model version in the GUI.  If I use 1.9, I can get predictions back but it gives me pause for concern since the versions are mismatched.

Having said that, the docs here seem to indicate that 1.10 is supported: https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/runtime-version-list.

How can I create a model version using Tensorflow 1.10?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems the document in the link you provided has updated the following:

> Note: The default AI Platform runtime version used by the AI Platform
>   Training and
>       Prediction API is version 1.0. When you submit training job requests and deploy models,
>       you must specify your desired runtime version. Otherwise, AI Platform uses version 1.0. 
>       See how to set runtime versions.

Example:

```
gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training my_job \
    --module-name trainer.task \
    --job-dir gs://my/training/job/directory \
    --package-path /path/to/my/project/trainer \
    --python-version 3.5
    --region us-central1 \
    --runtime-version 1.13
```